# gnat gprbuild : how to build a dynamic dll and link with a static c++ library

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries, ada

I have a full Ada project I want to build to get a dynamic dll.
Therefore I have to link it with another static library (myanotherlibrary.lib).

I use this command line :

```
gprbuild -d "D:\My_grp_project\My_grp_project.gpr"
```

Here the content of the .gpr :

```
project My_grp_project is

  Architecture := "x86";

  for Languages use ("Ada");
  for Source_Dirs use (".", "source", "source\common");
  for Library_Dir use "dll\" & Architecture;
  for Library_Ali_Dir use "ali\" & Architecture;
  for Library_Name use "My_grp_project";
  for Library_Kind use "dynamic";
  for Object_Dir use "obj\" & Architecture;

  package Linker is
   for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-L.", "-lbar");
  end Linker;

end My_grp_project;
```

I put "myanotherlibrary.lib" in the directory "D:\My_grp_project\", but it still doesn't link: "undefined reference to ..."

Could anyone help me please ?

Regards
Glen

Comment: Linking Ada to a C++ library... in Ada, the Import pragmas will have to supply the C++ mangled version of each object (function) name for the Ada code to find it. See http://wiki.ada-dk.org/c_bindings_example Is this your problem? If not, please edit an actual linker error message into the example.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I do get the C++ mangled name of my method "Initialize" : "Initialize@MyObject_Interface@@SAXPBDAAW4T_MyObject_Status@@@Z (public: static void __cdecl MyObject_Interface::Initialize(enum T_MyObject_Status &))". Still the linker doesn't want to resolve reference "undefined reference to `initialize'". On my .ads file I write : procedure initialize (Status : out T_MyObject_Status)
   is
      procedure C_Initialize (pStatus : out T_MyObject_Status);
      pragma Import (CPP, C_Initialize, "Initialize");
   begin
      C_Initialize(pStatus => Status);
   end initialize;

Comment: And I think that may be the problem : you need `pragma Import (CPP, C_Initialize, "c++_mangled_Initialize");` as in the example I linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html#Library-Projects), I think you should be using the `Library_Options` attribute instead of `package Linker`:

```
for Library_Options use ("-L.", "-lbar”);
```

(I’m confused - do you mean `myanotherlibrary.lib` or `bar.lib`?)

I’d be a bit concerned about using a static library from a dynamic library: I’d expect the dynamic library to be built with `-fPIC` or equivalent switch to get position-independent code, so that the same loaded library binary can be seen at different addresses in each of the executables using it.

Comment: Thank you Simon.
I changed my .gpr file to something like that :
 'project My_grp_project is'

  '... same as before without package linker...'

  'for Library_Options use ("-Ld:\.", "-lmyanotherlibrary");'
 
 'end My_grp_project;'

Now the linker do find my "myanotherlibrary.lib" located on "d:\" but it still doesn't resolve reference (see my comment to Brian post)

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution I finally found.

1. It is not possible to link static library compiled with MSVC. I had to compile my static library with GCC (same version as the one included in GNAT).
2. I had to add "Library_Options" options, without "-L" and "-l" arguments (another problem I passed). Note that package Linker is not taken into account while building a dynamic library. Note also that paths shall have no spaces !

```
project My_grp_project is

  for Languages use ("Ada");
  for Source_Dirs use (".", "source", "source\common");
  for Library_Dir use “dll";
  for Library_Ali_Dir use "ali";
  for Object_Dir use "obj";

  for Library_Name use "My_grp_project";
  for Library_Kind use "dynamic";
  for Library_Options use ("path\myanotherlibrary.a", "path_to_GNAT\libstdc++.a");

end My_grp_project;
```

1. I builded the project in the GPS (default option) : "Build All"
2. In result I do have my dynamic library "libMy_grp_project.dll"

Voilà.
Thanks !